# How to delete multiple object from array in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

i have array like this:

```
     const data = [
          {
            id: '1',
          
            Products:[{
            ProductID: '1',
            },
            {
            ProductID: '2',
            },,
            {
            ProductID: '3',
            }]
           },
          {
            id: '2',
            Products:[{
            ProductID: '1',
            }]
          }
       ]
```

i want to remove items like this:

i send id which is data id, and products,like this:

```
dispatch({
      type: "delete",
      payload: { id, products },
    });
```

> for example: id : 1 products : [{ ProductID: '1'},{ ProductID: '2'}]

*so this method will delete data item which is id == 1 and objects which are sent*

*i tried this:*

```
return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map((content, i) =>
          content.id === action.payload.id 
            ? {
                ...content,
                Products: content.Products.filter(
                  (item) => {
                    return action.payload.products.map((product) => {
                      product.id != item.id;
                    });
                  }
                ),
              }
            : content
        ),
      };
```

Comment: Do you want to remove object related to `id` or `Products`?

Comment: i want to remove objects related to id. if i send two object, i want to remove them from products @AdityaS.

Comment: So according to your example, you want to remove `ProductID: 1` & `ProductID: 2` from object `id: 1`, right?

Comment: right @AdityaS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
return {
...state,
data: state.data.map((content, i) =>
    content.id === action.payload.id ?
    {
        ...content,
        Products: content.Products.filter(
            item => action.payload.products.find(product => product.id != item.id);
        ),
    } :
    content),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to comments, you can filter products from sub-object like this,

```
return {
   ...state,
   data: state.data.map((content, i) => {
      if (content.id != action.payload.id) {
         return content;
      } else {
         return {
            id: content.id,
            Products: content.Products.filter(i => {
               if (!action.payload.products.find(p => p.ProductId == i.ProductId) return i)
            })
         }
      }
   }
};
```

Try this code here,

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: "1",
        Products: [
            {
                ProductID: "1",
            },
            {
                ProductID: "2",
            },
            {
                ProductID: "3",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        Products: [
            {
                ProductID: "1",
            },
        ],
    },
]

function deleteRecord(id, products) {
    return data.map((item) => {
        if (item.id != id) {
            return item
        } else {
            return {
                id: item.id,
                Products: item.Products.filter((i) => {
                    if (!products.find((p) => p.ProductID == i.ProductID)) return i
                }),
            }
        }
    })
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(deleteRecord("1", [{ ProductID: "1" }, { ProductID: "2" }])))
```